# Vertical spacing inside a table-cell

Tags: css, html-table, flexbox, justify

I'm currently trying to simulate a `text-align: justify`, but vertically and between divs.

I have 4 `div`inside a `td` like this :

```
<td>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</td>
```

But their total height is not as high as the height of the td, so they all stack vertically in the middle.
Is there a way to put some space between them, like a justified content?

Comment: I guess there's no way to know at design time what the height of the td is, and divide that height by 4?

Comment: No, the height is changing constantly. The height of each div is also changing.

Comment: I tested a bit with a flex container - see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/9upb92zm/1/) - and it looks promising, but I'm not convinced it will work in all circumstances.

Comment: The thing is, you can't change the `display` value of a table cell and expect it to keep working as expected. So I'm not posting this for an answer.

Comment: I already tried with flexbox, but it simplly annihilates the display of the rest of my table, so I can't really use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I managed to achieve what I was looking for.
I'll post it here for those potentially having the same issue.

Basically you have to set your **tr** and **td**'s height to **100%**.

Then, set your container to **height: 100%** and **display: flex;**, giving it a **justify-content** of **space-around** or **space-between** depending of what you need.
Don't forget **flex-direction: column** if your divs are not necesseraly 100% width.

> HTML

```
<td>
  <div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</td>
```

> CSS

```
tr,td{
  height: 100%;
}

td>div{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```